# How to hide top header bar with back button while using jqxChart of jqWidget for iOS app.

Tags: jqwidget

I am using jqxChart of jqWidget. I am not writing any code for displaying a top bar with back button but when i use below line of code in html body then it loads chart with top bar with Back button.

```
<body class='default'>
<div id="demoContainer" class="device-mobile-tablet">
    <div id="container" class="device-mobile-tablet-container">
        <div id='jqxChart' style="margin-top: 50px; width: 100%; height: 49.0797%; position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Please help me hide this top bar and back button

Answer (score 0):

Leave only:

```
<div id='jqxChart' style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
```

The [jQWidgets Chart](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxchart/index.htm) does not have any header or back button. Initialize the Chart widget and it look on mobile, the same way it looks on desktop. I would suggest you however to set its width and height in percentages as in the sample code, so the Chart's size will depend on the device's screen size. Make sure to add 100% height to the Body and HTML tags, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default mobile template provided by jqwidget team then "toolbar with back button" would be appear by default. 
You can remove that top header (toolbar) with back button by placing below specified javascript code after the method call

```
initSimulator("grid");
```

inside function call

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     //Grid setup..
     //....
     //...
    initSimulator("grid"); 

    // ************* Remove Top Toolbar with Back Button *********
    var toolbar = document.getElementById("demoToolbar");
    toolbar.parentNode.removeChild(toolbar);
    $("#container").css('padding-top', '0px');
    // ====================== XXXXXXXXXXXXX =====================

 });
```

Assuming your HTML body is like :

```
<body class='default'>
<div id="demoContainer" class="device-mobile-tablet">
    <div id="container" class="device-mobile-tablet-container" style="margin-top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0px;">
        <div id='jqxgrid'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```